# How do I prepare a technical report containing nothing but mathematics for someone who has no higher education?

Tags: documentation, portfolio

I am currently working for a man who is very smart, but to the best of my knowledge has taken no college courses. I would like to prepare a report for him detailing original but very simple (freshman-level) math work that I did relating to a problem we encountered. This presents a number of challenges.

- If I use a format resembling a formal academic paper I fear I will lose his interest. Conversely, I would like to prepare something that I could use in my portfolio. Is there a happy medium between the two?
- I realize I have the option of writing something like a brief summary in addition to a longer portfolio piece. Even if I go that route, where would I look for sample formats? Is there an appreciable difference between academic formats for such documents and what is used in the workplace? What is a good reference for *formats* of such documents, as opposed to *samples* (fairly readily available IMO)?

Comment: I was taking college level math in HS, don't underestimate him.

Comment: Why are you preparing this?  Is it in response to something he requested?

Comment: Sort of. There is a fine-motor manual labor task that anyone in the shop needs to be able to do. It involves a measurement that they've been eyeballing and I found a way to calculate it with a fair amount of precision.

Answer (score 7):

Write it in view of the end audience you desire. If you think this is people who would like it academic style, then do it that way. Your boss is not the end audience in view of your question.

Don't underestimate your boss, by all means summarise in plain language, but don't assume he can't understand. I left school at 14 but have no trouble following theory in a multitude of disciplines. There's nothing special about a college education that self-educated people cannot learn.

Comment: +1 for "Don't underestimate your boss" he is his boss for a reason! Courses are not the only way to learn, and underestimating someone higher up than you purely based on "education" is a bad way to approach things.

Comment: +1 I wonder if he'd feel the need to explain freshman math to Bill Gates